# can I create a view of items from my menus

Tags: views, routes

Is it possible to create a view (listing) from a menu ?

I'm trying to find tutorials on using menu_views or maixmenu but i'm not having any luck.

Comment: Hey Baybook, What is your requirement? Do you want to show all menus in a view or menu item list using a view

Comment: I want to show certain menu items in a list. For example.  Menu 1
   item 1
   item 2
   item 3
Menu 2
   item 4
   item 5
   item 6
   
I want to be able to place item1-3 in a block and display on a page.  Same for items 4-6